# Count number of posts have particular meta key or value?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

What I want to achieve is display the number of posts which have particular meta key or value I am getting a list of posts and meta key and value but don't know how to display them I'm storing data using repeatable fields. Storing work properly.
Now, for example, I have age meta value in two posts so how can I count no of a post with age. Age = No of post 2.

My Code :

```
global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'repeatable_fields') ");
$array = wp_json_encode($query);
print_r($array);
```

Outout :

> [{"meta_id":"312","post_id":"108","meta_key":"repeatable_fields","meta_value":"a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"Zaheer\";s:5:\"phone\";s:3:\"123\";}i:1;a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"Sageer\";s:5:\"phone\";s:11:\"09190219218\";}}"},{"meta_id":"323","post_id":"121","meta_key":"repeatable_fields","meta_value":"a:2:{i:0;a:2:{s:9:\"iif_label\";s:4:\"City\";s:11:\"iif_details\";s:7:\"karachi\";}i:1;a:2:{s:9:\"iif_label\";s:3:\"Age\";s:11:\"iif_details\";s:2:\"12\";}}"},{"meta_id":"329","post_id":"126","meta_key":"repeatable_fields","meta_value":"a:1:{i:0;a:2:{s:9:\"iif_label\";s:3:\"Age\";s:11:\"iif_details\";s:2:\"12\";}}"},{"meta_id":"332","post_id":"128","meta_key":"repeatable_fields","meta_value":"a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:9:\"iif_label\";s:7:\"Country\";s:11:\"iif_details\";s:8:\"Pakistan\";}i:1;a:2:{s:9:\"iif_label\";s:4:\"City\";s:11:\"iif_details\";s:9:\"Islamabad\";}i:2;a:2:{s:9:\"iif_label\";s:3:\"Age\";s:11:\"iif_details\";s:2:\"12\";}}"}]

Comment: Are you using Advanced Custom Fields to create these custom fields?

Comment: No i am just using wordpress add_meta_boxes

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
$count_age = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
    "
    SELECT      count(meta_id)
    FROM        {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
    WHERE       meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%'
    ",
    'Age'
));
```

More about `get_col()` here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Column

Comment: it's working if i create above code but i have alot of values age , country , city , range etc 1000 options. When i am creating above code inside loop it showing .

Country

City

Age
Array ( [0] => 22 )
Age
Array ( [0] => 22 )

Comment: Here is my code.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xuPTNRjFoiy9W-2qjmoWAmcsaIYdCOej/view?usp=sharing)